# Valor mais recorrente em uma janela de tempo específica em SQL

Tags: sql, bigquery

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
table user
user_id |  mes_ano   | frutas  
------------------------------
1       | 2021-01    | maçã
1       | 2021-01    | melão
1       | 2021-01    | laranja
1       | 2021-02    | uva
1       | 2021-02    | laranja
1       | 2021-02    | kiwi
1       | 2021-03    | uva
1       | 2021-03    | pera
1       | 2021-03    | banana
1       | 2021-04    | laranja
1       | 2021-04    | kiwi
1       | 2021-04    | banana
1       | 2021-05    | uva
1       | 2021-05    | pera
1       | 2021-05    | kiwi
```

e quero chegar no seguinte resultado:

```
user_id  |   mes_ano  |            frutas            |  mais_freq_2meses
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | 2021-01    | maçã, melão, laranja         | -
1        | 2021-02    | uva, laranja, kiwi           | laranja
1        | 2021-03    | uva, pera, banana            | uva
1        | 2021-04    | laranja, kiwi, banana        | banana
1        | 2021-05    | uva, pera, kiwi              | kiwi
```

Explicando: na última coluna quero mostrar a fruta mais recorrente nos últimos 2 meses, ou seja, a fruta mais recorrente em relação à linha atual e à linha anterior.

Com o código abaixo eu consegui listar a fruta mais recorrente do período total dos meus dados. Por exemplo, a fruta mais recorrente em 12 meses em uma tabela com registro para 12 meses. Como faço para aplicar esta lógica a uma window específica de tempo?

```
select * from (
  select user_id, mes_ano, 
    string_agg(distinct frutas) as frutas  
  from user
  group by  user_id, mes_ano  
) join (
  select user_id, frutas  
  from user
  group by user_id, frutas  
  qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by user_id order by count(*) desc)
)
using (user_id)
```

Comment: *"Como faço para aplicar esta lógica a uma window específica de tempo?"* já tentou agrupar por data? Depois pode filtar só a janela de data que deseja

Comment: O que sua query retorna ? Creio que baste , como disse o colega ,  colocar um "where" do tempo.